# In Jetpack Compose, how do i apply a font/typeface stored in Assets?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack compose, the documentation suggests applying fonts using the `font-family` attributes and referring to font files stored in `res/fonts` folder. Is it also possible to use font files stored under `assets/` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is default method which takes `AssetManager` as an argument:

```kotlin
/**
 * Create a Font declaration from a file in the assets directory. The content of the [File] is
 * read during construction.
 *
 * @param assetManager Android AssetManager
 * @param path full path starting from the assets directory (i.e. dir/myfont.ttf for
 * assets/dir/myfont.ttf).
 * @param weight The weight of the font. The system uses this to match a font to a font request
 * that is given in a [androidx.compose.ui.text.SpanStyle].
 * @param style The style of the font, normal or italic. The system uses this to match a font to a
 * font request that is given in a [androidx.compose.ui.text.SpanStyle].
 */
@ExperimentalTextApi
@OptIn(InternalPlatformTextApi::class, ExperimentalTextApi::class)
@Stable
fun Font(
    assetManager: AssetManager,
    path: String,
    weight: FontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
    style: FontStyle = FontStyle.Normal
): Font = AndroidAssetFont(assetManager, path, weight, style)
```

now access font like this!

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
@Composable
fun fontFamily() = FontFamily(
    Font(LocalContext.current.assets,"myfont.ttf")
)

@Composable
fun typography() = Typography(

    h1 = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = fontFamily(),
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        fontSize = 30.sp
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Create font directory in res (res/font)
2. copy your .ttf fonts in res/font
3. find the Type.kt file ( in ui/theme directory )
4. create a variable for font in Type.kt

   ```
   val MyCustomFont = FontFamily(
       Font(R.font.regular),
       Font(R.font.bold,FontWeight.Bold)
   )
   ```
5. there is Typography val in Type.kt file, you can change the entire app's font family by putting defaultFontFamily = MyCustomFont in this val

   ```
   val Typography = Typography(
       defaultFontFamily = MyCustomFont,
       body1 = TextStyle(
           fontFamily = MyCustomFont2,
           fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
           fontSize = 16.sp
    ),
   ```
6. you can set font family to specific typography like body1, h1, h2, ...

Edit: to change font for Material 3 add the following in Type.kt

```
bodyLarge = TextStyle(
    fontFamily = MyCustomFont,
    fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
    fontSize = 16.sp,
    lineHeight = 24.sp,
    letterSpacing = 0.5.sp
),
displayLarge= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
displayMedium= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
displaySmall= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
headlineLarge= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
headlineMedium= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
headlineSmall= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
titleLarge= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
titleMedium= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
titleSmall= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
bodyMedium= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
bodySmall= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
labelLarge= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
labelMedium= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
labelSmall= TextStyle(fontFamily = MyCustomFont),
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually in compose, there is usually a class named Typography.kt, which is used by the `MaterialTheme` Composable. As described in the Theme Codelab, the correct way is to modify this class to add your fonts to it. You see actually, you can create your own `mAppTheme` to override Material's.

https://youtu.be/DDd6IOlH3io?t=6m27s

This video showcases implementing custom color palettes, but a similar approach can be taken to implement custom typography.

Check the JetSnack sample app
https://github.com/android/compose-samples